# How to allocate more storage space to kali linux?

Tags: partition, kali-linux

I have recently installed Kali Linux along with my Windows installation, but I found out I messed up on the amount of storage space I have allocated. As you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcem9.png) image, I still have 230 GB of unallocated space left, and I would like to allocate half of this to Kali, and the other half to Windows.

My question is, how do I allocate more storage to Kali without reinstalling?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: @GAD3R I think this question could be applied to any Linux OS, not specifically Kali. Even tho OP mentioned Kali. I would understand if the question was "How to setup this tool in Kali, or why is this tool not working".

No reason to just mark it as duplicate **just** because OP is using Kali.

Comment: You can use Gparted to extend your neighbouring partition which are adjacent to your unallocated partition.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson [Is it safe?](https://gparted.org/faq.php#faq-6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to modify the partitioning you already have.

1. Use Gparted to create a new ext4 partition from the unallocated space (probably /dev/sda11 judging from your picture)
2. Create a mount point (directory)

   ```
   mkdir /media/youruserame/whateveryouwant
   ```
3. Insert a new item in /etc/fstab so that this mounts at all future boots

   ```
   /dev/sda11   /media/youruserame/whateveryouwant   ext4   defaults   0   2
   ```
4. Then just mount with

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

All of the unallocated space is now available to you.

Since /dev/sda4 is your Windows installation, if you format the partition as ntfs rather than ext4 (and make the change in fstab too) then all the data on this partition will be available to you in Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at: https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted

NOTE the bit that is written in red:

> It is very important that you back up all your data before you modify
>   your partitions with GParted. If all goes well, no data should be
>   lost, but you can never know!

PROCEED WITH CAUTION. You may lose data!!!

Basically, you can use GParted. RIGHT click on the partition you want to change (NOT the table at the top) and choose Resize/Move